# Can't make my do loop stop when it is done

Tags: vba, web-scraping, boolean-expression

I've written a script in vba which is scraping data from a certain site very smoothly. I was trying to do the same in an unconventional way. The loop I have used in my script is continuing on and on. I need to apply a logic here so that when the value of "Y" is None it will stop rolling. The Value of Y is number here. I could use for loop to accomplish this but i tried this way to make sure if I want to run my crawler without knowing how many pages are there to crawl. Thanks in advance.

```
Sub Aoty_Data()
Dim http As New XMLHTTP60
Dim html As New HTMLDocument, topic As HTMLHtmlElement

y = 1
Do

With http
    .Open "GET", "http://www.albumoftheyear.org/ratings/6-highest-rated/2000/" & y, False
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With

For Each topic In html.getElementsByClassName("albumListRow")
    x = x + 1
    With topic.getElementsByClassName("listLargeTitle")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")
        If .Length Then Cells(x, 1) = Split(.Item(0).innerText, "-")(0)
    End With
        With topic.getElementsByClassName("listLargeTitle")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")
        If .Length Then Cells(x, 2) = Split(.Item(0).innerText, "-")(1)
    End With
Next topic
y = y + 1
Loop Until y = ""   'I used y="" cause the editor did not let me leave it blank.

End Sub
```

Comment: You never assign anything to `y` that would cause it to become an empty string.  You're always incrementing it.  It seems like you need a check on the http response if you got valid data back.

Comment: y can never be an empty string.

Comment: Right you are sir, Nathan_sav. I did it definitely the wrong way, that is because I seek help. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: You are right Sobigen. Actually, I can't find any idea how to accomplish this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you come up with your own solution yet? One answer is within a different question: How does this "certain site" behave when the GET route exceeds the valid number of pages ...? It seems to return the first page of results. Note that I haven't CHANGED your existing code at all, just re-factored a little bit and added a test for whether or not the first artist/album has been returned a second time.

```
Sub Aoty_Data()
    Dim http As New XMLHTTP60
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument, topic As HTMLHtmlElement

    y = 1
    numberOneAlbumForYear = ""
    Do
        http.Open "GET", "http://www.albumoftheyear.org/ratings/6-highest-rated/2000/" & y, False
        http.send
        html.body.innerHTML = http.responseText
        For Each topic In html.getElementsByClassName("albumListRow")
            x = x + 1
            With topic.getElementsByClassName("listLargeTitle")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")
                Debug.Print .Item(0).innerText
                If .Length Then
                    Cells(x, 1) = Split(.Item(0).innerText, "-")(0)
                    Cells(x, 2) = Split(.Item(0).innerText, "-")(1)
                End If
            End With
            If y = 1 And numberOneAlbumForYear = "" Then
                numberOneAlbumForYear = Cells(x, 1) & Cells(x, 2)
            ElseIf (Cells(x, 1) & Cells(x, 2)) = numberOneAlbumForYear Then
                Rows(x).ClearContents
                Exit Do
            End If
        Next topic
        y = y + 1
    Loop 'Until y = "" [don't need this condition at all].
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks JeffB, for your answer. It works perfectly. Thanks a ton.